# Handling textbox input validation with a regex

Tags: .net, regex, textbox

I need to validate some textbox input. I want to use a regex.

The question:

> Where do I test my regex against the textbox input?

By using the KeyPress event I can only access the old text of the textbox. I cant access the text with the new input included. How do I include the textbox text with the new input? 
I could just do   `text = text + input`, but that ignores the fact that the input could be in the middle of the text, not always at the end. Any ideas?

---

Below is the text of the function in case it is useful.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    Dim decimalRex As Regex = New Regex("^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$")'checks for decimal'

    If decimalRex.IsMatch(sender.Text) Then'notice this only tests the text, not the input'
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If
 End Sub
```

---

### EDIT:

I ended up not including one of the requirements I needed. I wanted to be able to sanitize the input to the textbox on the fly, and making sure the bad input never appears in the textbox.
I accepted the best answer to my question, even though that is what I needed. The solution to what I needed is below:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = False
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." Then
        If InStr(sender.text, ".") > 0 Then
            e.Handled = True
        Else
            e.Handled = False
        End If
    ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should use the RegularExpressionValidator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to capture non-matching characters for each key, and this method could easily be modified to do what you're asking... however see below.

```
Private Sub ONSTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not characterRegex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString()) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If you're attempting to validate the full string, you really should be using the Validating event, and do a regex of the full string there.

```
Private Sub ONSTextBox_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Validating
    If Not validationRegex.IsMatch(Text) Then
        errorProvider.SetError(Me, "Error Message Here")
        e.Cancel = True ' Keeps them from changing to another control until error is corrected.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Accepted as the best answer to my original question, though not the best answer to what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do this in the `EditValueChanged` Event of the TextBox

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx) event and validate your text there (if you don't use something fancier like bindings on your text).